# automation of subset process

Tags: r, subset

It is probably easy, but I can't figure it out.
I have a data frame with over 70 variables. I make predictions using all those variables. For sensitivity analysis I would like to subset the data frame automatically to see how the prediction performs on this specific subset.
I have done this manually but with over 100 different subset options it is very tedious.

Here is the data/code and my desired solution:

```
n = c(2, 3, 5) 
s = c("aa", "bb", "cc") 
b = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)
a = c(1.7, 3.3, 5.1) 
df = data.frame(n, s, b, a)

df
```

To calculate the accuracy of prediction a

```
df$calc <- df$a - df$n
df$difference <- sqrt(df$calc * df$calc)
```

With these values I can now calculate the Mean and SD

```
Mean <- mean(df$difference)
SD <- sd(df$difference)
```

Let's say I would like to get an overview of the prediction accuracy for all cases where b = TRUE. (Or other subsets of the data)
Ideally I would like a data frame to look like this:

```
subset = c("b=TRUE", "b=FALSE", "s=aa") 
amount = c(2, 1, 1) # count the number this subset occurs
Mean = c(0.22, 0.3, 0.1)
SD = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.5) 
OV = data.frame(subset, amount, Mean, SD)

OV
```

Considering that I have more than 100 different subsets that I would like to create, I need a fast solution that generates an overview like the OV data frame. I tried a loop, but I have trouble defining a vector for subsetting the data.

Thanks!

Comment: You have a logical column.  So you can subset it based on that column `i1 <- df$b;df$a[i1] - df$n[i1]`  If you have many groups, use the 'b' column as group and do the operation by group.

Comment: What is this `sqrt(df$calc * df$calc)` mishmas? Are you just trying to do `abs(df$calc)`? You could do this in the `df$difference <- abs(df$a - df$n)` on the fly

Comment: Perhaps `df %>% group_by(b) %>% summarise(amount = n(), Mean = mean(sqrt((a-n)^2)), Sd = sd(sqrt((a-n)^2)))`